# how can I have max blur with imageresizer asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-resizing, blur, imageresizer

I need to add blur to uploaded images in my project. I want my images look like [this](http://img.imageresizer.io/84y5ktaTIp/Lightbulb-moment.jpg?size=25%25&blur=100) I'm using imageresizer advancedfilters plugin setting blur to 100 but result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1J8K.jpg)

There is a size query in the example and that is not working on my code. Is there another plugin for that ?

Comment: The current implementation of blurring is too slow to blur that much. Rather than a Gaussian blur, we need a box blur approximation. This should arrive with Imageflow.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported - yet (see comment).

I would suggest combining client-side CSS blur and upscaling (if you can). This has the side effect of saving tremendous bandwidth.

Comment: unfortunately mobile devices will use those images so I should have physical files on server. In fact i need that blur image for preview like whatsapp does before the real image ready to show there is a blurred one which has same dimensions but smaller file size. Is there a way to do this in asp.net web api 2 instead of imageresizer?

Comment: Like Medium? https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/